# What is Wrong with Ubuntu 14.04? Font Rendering Bugs

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, graphics, fonts

My Ubuntu is being very very irritating after upgrading to 14.04. Every once in a blue moon, certain glyphs just disappear from the screen.

Every once in a while, (even as I'm writing this question), all my `i`'s are disappearing, with nothing being shown instead.

[image]

Actually, check this out:

---

Before typing **more**:  [image]

---

After typing m**o**re: [image]

---

This is a system-wide problem, some screenshots from Firefox, Nautilus, etc:

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

How do I fix these errors?

*I have the nVidia graphics driver installed right now, but even with a pristine install (with the **nouveau** driver, this problem was there)*

Comment: I have the same problem without installing ubuntu, I just selected Try Ubuntu from live cd. But this scared me off from installing.

Comment: If it's system-wide, sounds like an issue with graphics card. But I'm not very knowledgeable in that

Comment: Maybe related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/584922/how-do-i-fix-fonts-not-rendering-and-missing-letters

Comment: Which nvidia driver version?

Comment: It's 331.113 (`nvidia-xconfig --version`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen similar problems with 14.04. They seemed to be fixed in 14.10, and even better in 15.04 (this latter, specifically regarding nVidia cards). So upgrading will probably be worth a try.

The underlying problem seems to be a bug within Unity itself. I have not encountered anything like it on XFCE, KDE or Cinnamon. If you do not wish to install a full system (maybe on a second partition?), you could try one of these desktop managers, see if it plays better with your graphics card.

HTH.

Comment: I have a strong doubt that it could  be unity itself too, although I don't know how to verify this. Anyways, thanks for the answer.

Comment: @kumar_harsh There are instructions on installing another desktop manager here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/65083/what-kinds-of-desktop-environments-and-shells-are-available  You can have both Unity and Gnome-shell (for example) installed at the same time, and switch from one to another in the login screen.

Comment: Thanks for the links. I'm sure someone will find them useful. (*I'm already aware of those things, just not motivated enough to go through the hassle of changing the DE again* :P). As it stands, Unity has been buggy for quite some time and makes me throw up a little, but Gnome3 is not so good either. Have given LXDE a try a long time ago (looked stable, but badly dated UI). But this lamentation is for another post anyways, so let's stop it at that.